# Java stream merge and output

Tags: java, java-stream, guava

I have a list of objects of the form:

```
public class Child
{
    private Mom mom;
    private Dad dad;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private boolean isAdopted;
}
```

I need to transform this list into a list of a different data structure, aggregating objects with the same Mom and Dad keys together into the form

```
public class Family
{
    private Mom mom;
    private Dad dad;
    private Map<String, int> kids;
}
```

where the 'kids' map is a map of all children names to ages.

Currently, I am doing this translation as follows:

```
public Collection<Family> transform( final Collection<Child> children )
{
    return children.stream()
                   .filter( child -> !child.getIsAdopted() )
                   .collect( ImmutableTable.toImmutableTable( child -> child.getMom(),
                                                              child -> child.getDad(),
                                                              child -> new HashMap<>(child.getName(), child.getAge() ),
                                                              (c1, c2) -> { 
                                                                  c1.getKids().putAll(c2.getKids());
                                                                  return c1;
                                                              } ) )
                   .cellSet()
                   .stream()
                   .map( Table.Cell::getValue)
                   .collect( Collectors.toList() );
}
```

Is there a way for me to do this without needing to collect to the intermediary table before transforming to the final list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could define a `GroupingKey` with `mom` and `dad` attributes, the implementation could be simplified to:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
class GroupingKey {
    Mom mom;
    Dad dad;
}

public List<Family> transformer( final Collection<Child> children ) {
    return children.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(c -> new GroupingKey(c.getMom(), c.getDad())),
                    map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                            .map(e -> new Family(e.getKey().getMom(), e.getKey().getDad(),
                                    e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Child::getName, Child::getAge))))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())));
}
```

or if not by defining any other class, you can cast the objects with the same approach as :

```
public List<Family> transform( final Collection<Child> children ) {
    return children.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(c -> Arrays.asList(c.getMom(), c.getDad())),
                    map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                            .map(e -> new Family(((Mom) ((List) e.getKey()).get(0)), ((Dad) ((List) e.getKey()).get(1)),
                                    e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Child::getName, Child::getAge))))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
public static Collection<Family> transform( final Collection<Child> children ) {
    Map<Mom, Map<Dad, Family>> families = new HashMap<>();
    for (Child child : children) {
        if (! child.isAdopted()) {
            families.computeIfAbsent(child.getMom(), k -> new HashMap<>())
                    .computeIfAbsent(child.getDad(), k -> new Family(child.getMom(), child.getDad(), new HashMap<>()))
                    .getKids().put(child.getName(), child.getAge());
        }
    }
    return families.values().stream().flatMap(m -> m.values().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```